# Is my mass relative?

Tags: gravity, mass

Mass is said to be a source of gravity (I think:p), but if I were to travel into space. Would it change with respect to someone on earth? Since the gravity changes in space, but does it affect the change of mass? I mean since mass is its source, then the mass should affect it and not it.. Am I thinking right?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160679/ (w.r.t. to the PE changing mass aspect here)

Answer (score 0):

No. Mass stays constant and never changes even in "zero gravity" environments.

Comment: Please consider extending your answer, otherwise make it a comment.